# Can I use CSS to appear and then disappear the border after one click?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

Thanks for reading. I am trying to check a function whether true of false. If false, I would like to change the border color to red, appear and disappear and appear and disappear in 2 seconds. I just tried the css animation to achieve it, but it only appear one time. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/38qvr0j3lp

I wonder if there is a way using CSS to achieve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: answered below. Try reducing the animation time to 600ms overall with 150ms for each transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little demo - on click I'm adding an `animation` (via `keyframes` instead of `transition`) to the button element.

The keyframe animation begins with a red border, and has a transparent border in the middle. By using this in conjunction with `steps(1)`, the animation is treated like it consists of two frames (at `0%` and `50%`), alternating transparent and red. I run this animation twice (that's the `2`) over 1 second each time (that's the `1s`).

In the JS, note that I'm removing the `blink` class and readding it 10ms later in case it's already there. You can't retrigger a CSS keyframe animation without removing and readding the property.

```js
function blink(el) {
  el.classList.remove("blink")

  setTimeout(function() {
    el.classList.add("blink")
  }, 10);
}
```

```css
button {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
}

.blink {
  animation: border-blink 1s steps(1) 2;
}

@keyframes border-blink {
  0% {
    border-color: red;
  }

  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="blink(this)">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the code in your code sandbox with a totally React approach.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: false
    };
  }

  showErrorSignal() {
    this.setState({ error: true });
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ error: false }), 500);
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ error: true }), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ error: false }), 1500);
  }
  render() {
    const styles = {
      error: {
        borderWidth: 5,
        borderColor: "red"
      }
    };
    return (
      <div className="App" style={this.state.error ? styles.error : undefined}>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.showErrorSignal()}>
          show error signal
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid #d5edeb;
  transition-property: border-color, border-width;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```